# Script to join .csv file to shapefile and export changing column names

Tags: arcpy

I have a shapefile with an attribute table like this:

```
FID   Shape      ID
0     Polgyon    3 
1     Polgyon    3
2     Polygon    3
3     Polygon    3
```

and numerous csv files which look something like this:

```
FID   p-value  t-stat
0     0.50     0.0004
1     0.01     0.0006
2     0.02     0.0007
3     0.04     0.0008
```

and I am joining the csv files to the shapefile and then exporting like this:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

arcpy.env.workspace=r'H:\path_to_csv_files'
shapefile=r'H:\pathway_to_shapefile.shp'
out=r'H:\output_pathway'
#loop through csv files  
for table in arcpy.ListTables("*"):  
#Create a new feature layer, this will remove previous join  
  arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shapefile, "parcelLyr")  
#   Join table to feature layer  
  arcpy.AddJoin_management("parcelLyr", "FID", table, "FID", 'KEEP_COMMON') 
  tableName = table.split(".")[0] 
  if not os.path.isdir(out):
            os.mkdir(out)
#   #Export joined layer to new feature clas  
  arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("parcelLyr", out, tableName)
```

but my out put table looks like this:

```
FID   Shape      ID  NDVI__5_cs   NDVI__5__1
0     Polgyon    3   0.50         0.0004
1     Polgyon    3   0.01         0.0006
2     Polygon    3   0.02         0.0007 
3     Polygon    3   0.04         0.0008
```

`NDVI_5.csv` is the name of my first csv file so it is for some reason putting the name of the csv file as the column headers after the join.  When I do the join manually in arcgis this doesn't happen though.

Comment: Try JoinField http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000, it does everything your script does in one line. You might want to edit your column headers, dashes in field names are not allowed.

Comment: I will look into it,  I removed all the dashes and the same problem is still there.

Comment: Also the Fully Qualified Field Names setting http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000008000000 set to False may help in your join, it should prevent the join name being used in the field name (i.e. p_value instead of NDVI_5_CSV.p_value) which is being shortened to the maximum field name length for a shape file by FeatureClassToFeatureClass.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson It looks like enough in your two answers to write a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> Try JoinField
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000,
>   it does everything your script does in one line. You might want to
>   edit your column headers, dashes in field names are not allowed.

and:

> Also the Fully Qualified Field Names setting
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000008000000
>   set to False may help in your join, it should prevent the join name
>   being used in the field name (i.e. p_value instead of
>   NDVI_5_CSV.p_value) which is being shortened to the maximum field name
>   length for a shape file by FeatureClassToFeatureClass.